# Fadeout effect is not working using wow animation?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to make fadeOut effect on click but this is not working properly. I have to use just CSS not javascript or jquery.

My Code:-

```js
$(function() {
    new WOW().init();
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fadeOut1 {
    animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js" integrity="sha256-z6FznuNG1jo9PP3/jBjL6P3tvLMtSwiVAowZPOgo56U=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha256-PHcOkPmOshsMBC+vtJdVr5Mwb7r0LkSVJPlPrp/IMpU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png-hd-11.png" width="200p/x" class="wow fadeOut">
```

I'm using `wow animation`.

Problem is if i want to fadeOut then why this is display back after fadOut effect on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` property to `fadeOut` class to make the animation stay at the last keyframe when it ends.

```js
$(function() {
    new WOW().init();
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fadeOut {
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js" integrity="sha256-z6FznuNG1jo9PP3/jBjL6P3tvLMtSwiVAowZPOgo56U=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha256-PHcOkPmOshsMBC+vtJdVr5Mwb7r0LkSVJPlPrp/IMpU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png-hd-11.png" width="200p/x" class="wow fadeOut">
```